# How do I alter table VARCHAR mysql Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql

I used the code below to change VARCHAR from (20) to (40) but no change happened in my table:

mysql> ALTER TABLE create_user modify email VARCHAR(40);

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: have you tried commiting your changes?  if other people are running your code and not producing the same behavior the next step is something with your set up. can you run the "commit" command and then see what happens?

Comment: Thanks! After running "commit" the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But i use your code can　accomplish.

mysql> desc create_user;

+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |

+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

| email | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> Alter table create_user modify email varchar(20);

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> desc create_user;

+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |

+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

| email | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment you should run commit but that also means your auto commit settings are different from the default. you may want to look into that further to prevent future headaches

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html